# Excel... Sum a row of values based on a character in the value

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, sumifs

I have 31 columns representing each day of the month.  I have 2 housekeepers cleaning rooms. The rows represent the villa numbers from 1 to 18.
Housekeeper #1's name starts with "A" and housekeeper #2's name starts with "L"
I need to total the number of cleaning hours for housekeeper #1 in column AG and housekeeper #2 in column AH.  The hours spent cleaning is a digit on the right side of the name.

The cells go across a row from B5:AF5 and look like this

Ann4__Ann3__Ann7__Lisa2__Lisa4__Ann4__Lisa1

For the "Ann" hours totals in AG5 I have tried using SUMIFS with this formula

=SUMIFS(right(B5:AF5),left(B5:AF5),"A")  but Excel returns an error.

I also tried SUMIF for the number of hours for Ann

=SUMIF(LEFT(B5:AF5),"A","(RIGHT(B5:AF5)*1))  Excel still says error.

The hours digit after each name is text, so I tried multiplying the result by 1 to convert to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

For Ann:=SUM(IF(LEFT(A1:D1,3)="ANN",RIGHT(A1:D1,1)*1,"")). For Lisa:=SUM(IF(LEFT(A1:D1,4)="Lisa",RIGHT(A1:D1,1)*1,"")). Both are Array entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>